# Float and Double question confusion - Java

Tags: java, floating-point, double, primitive-types

```
double basicPay = 1999.0;
        double hra = 145.0;
        float experience = 3.0f;
        double percentage;
        if(experience<3)percentage = 0;
        else if(experience>=3 && experience<5)percentage = 5;
        else if(experience>=5 && experience<10)percentage = 7;
        else percentage = 12;
        double salary = (basicPay + hra + basicPay*(percentage/100));
        System.out.println(salary);
```

This shows output as 2243.95

But if I change

```
double salary = (float)(basicPay + hra + basicPay*(percentage/100));
```

The answer now is 2243.949951171875

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 0):

This is problem not related to Java, but to the standard of floating point numbers and their precision. Not all numbers can be represented with `float`. Instead of the exact value the floating point is going to get a value that is a closest approximation of the real value in floating point format. `double` has much more bytes to store the data, so it's more precise.

I won't go into explaining the whole thing because I believe there is plenty of resources which explain it very well, google `floating point precision`.

Comment: Java is partly responsible here; its default output of 2243.95 does not show the true value that was computed. If it did, it would be more apparent to people that both calculations include rounding errors.